# Agresti-Coull Confidence Interval question

Tags: confidence-interval, z-score

In an experiment two independent groups were asked to perform a task. In group A there were 15 subjects and in group b there where 13 subjects. There were 15 successes in A and 2 successes in B. The appropriate Agresti-Coull 95% C.I. for $p_A$ - $p_B$ is (using $z_{0.975}$ = 1.96)

The possible choices are:

(a) (0.7888, 1.0536)

(b) (0.7888, 1.0000)

(c) (0.0000, 0.7888)

(d) (0.0000, 1.0536)

(e) (0.0000, 1.0423)

I could not get any of the answers provided. I would prefer if someone could show my mistakes as well as the correct answer.

$\hat{P}_a=\dfrac{16}{17}$ and $\hat{n}_a = 17$

$\hat{P}_b=\dfrac{3}{15}$ and $\hat{n}_b = 15$

$\dfrac{16}{17}-\dfrac{3}{15} = 0.7412$

$
1.96 - \sqrt{\dfrac{\dfrac{16}{17}\cdot\dfrac{1}{17}}{17} + \dfrac{\dfrac{3}{15}\cdot\dfrac{13}{15}}{15}}
$

$= .2313$

$0.7412 \pm 0.2313 \rightarrow (0.5099, 0.9725)$

Comment: How did you get 16/17  for $p_a$ ... you should explain where this comes from...